# What Is The Path To A PnPFile In SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, pnp-powershell, file

In the Documents directory in Sharepoint online I have a sub-directory called Development and a file in there called FontDemoInfo.txt.

In the browser it looks like:

```
Documents > Development  FontDemoInfo.txt
```

How do I get that file with the `Get-PnPFile` command?

I connect to the Office365 Sharepoint with:

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
Connect-PnPOnline  "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Company"
```

Where `company` and `Company` are the (case-sensitive) default names set up for the site.

If I do `Get-PnPFile -Url "/Development/FontDemoInfo.txt" -AsFile` I get a `File Not found.` error.

I tried about 10 different combinations of url that I read about (e.g. prefixes with slash, no slash, /Documents, /sites, copy link from the browser etc) but I still can't get the file.

What is the correct way to get this document in Sharepoint using PnP PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format was in other answers

```
Get-PnPFile -Url "/sites/Company/Development/FontDemoInfo.txt" -AsFile
```

The key part of these answers is the start `/sites/Company/`

The main problem in this case though comes from how SharePoint is displaying the information.

As per the question, the browser shows `Documents > Development  FontDemoInfo.txt`

However, the `Documents` directory is misleading. Clicking on the file and inspecting the URL in the browser more closely shows that the directory is actually `Shared Documents`! I'm not sure why this is the case or why it isn't displayed like that in the browser.

Thus, to get this file the url is actually:

```
Get-PnPFile -Url "/sites/Company/Shared Documents/Development/FontDemoInfo.txt" -AsFile
```

Comment: Yes, the default Documents library's path is Shared Documents rather than Documents.

Glad you are finding the correct answer, then you could accept your own reply as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this

```
Get-PnPFile -Url "/sites/Company/Development/FontDemoInfo.txt" -AsFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Get-PnPFile` in below format:

```
Get-PnPFile -Url /sites/siteName/DocumentLibrary/Folder/file.extension -AsFile
```

For example:

```
Get-PnPFile -Url /sites/project/_catalogs/themes/15/company.spcolor -AsFile
```

This retrieves the file and returns it as a File object

```
Get-PnPFile -Url /sites/project/_catalogs/themes/15/company.spcolor -Path c:\temp -FileName company.spcolor -AsFile
```

This retrieves the file and downloads it to `c:\temp\company.spcolor`

You can find more information in documentation at: [Get-PnPFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/Get-PnPFile)

Answer (score 0):

The Url parameter should be the server relative url, in this case, the relative url is this:

```
/sites/Company/Development/FontDemoInfo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasted 20 minutes on this, so putting in here in case it helps someone else - an fyi that this can also be caused if you've connected to the wrong site with `Connect-PnPOnline` (I was connecting to several sites for various operations and forgot to change to the correct site before using Get-PnPFile).